# ajax with Jquery can't make working in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am writing a plugin for a wordpress, where I use jquery for AJAX.

Following code doesn't work. I expect to show the content in results div when I type in input box.

Here is the code I use for ajax request. It is located on my theme header file.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
//alert("sjsjs");

    $("#se").keypress(function(e){
       // e.preventDefault();
        var search_val=$("#se").val(); 
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "./wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: {
                action:'wpay_search', 
                search_string:search_val
            },
            success:function(data){
                $('#results').append(response);
            }
    });   
});
});
</script>
```

html content in template file

```
<form name="nn" action="" method="post"></br></br>
            <input id ="se" type="text" name="test" width="20" />
            <input type="submit" id="clicksubmit" value="Submit" />

        </form>
        <div id="results">val is: 


        </div>
```

Here is the code in plugin file

```
function wpay_search() {
    //global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $whatever = $_POST['search_val'];

    $whatever += 10;

        echo $whatever;

    die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}

add_action('wp_ajax_wpay_search', 'wpay_search');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wpay_search', 'wpay_search');
```

I am new to wordpress plugin writing. Can anybody tell that where I have done the mistake?

Comment: Please look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well one thing that obviously jumps out to me is this...

```
        success:function(data){
            $('#results').append(response);
        }
```

Should be...

```
        success:function(data){
            $('#results').append(data);
        }
```

Because you have no variable called `response`, you passed the function `data` as a variable, so you have to use that.

Also, you're passing `search_string` as a paremeter, when infact in your php file, the `$_POST` is looking for `search_val`.

So you need to send `search_val` as parameter and give your JavaScript `search_val` variable another variable name in the JavaScript, just for less confusion. In this case I made it `search`.

```
                action:'wpay_search', 
                search_val:search
```

So overall it should look something like this...

```
$("#se").keypress(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    var search=$("#se").val(); 
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "./wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            action:'wpay_search', 
            search_val:search
        },
        success:function(data){
            $('#results').append(data);
        }
    });   
  });
```